# Laravel 8 'npm run dev' fail to build

Tags: php, webpack, laravel-8

I'm coming to Laravel 8 and I have some problems when run 'npm run dev'. Here the issue

"ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation"

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHHEh.png)

Here is mi package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1"
}
```

}

Comment: can you show me the code of webpack.mix,js ?

Comment: Hi, already run. The issue was my Node version, I did update it and just works

Comment: Okay, which node version are you using? because me also facing this issue...

Comment: Node -v
->15.7.0
npm -v
->7.5.0